# Show modal to user when updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have made this modal and it shows only on first visit to the website

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(!Cookies.get('modalShown')) {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
            Cookies.set('modalShown', true);
        } else {
            alert('You already saw the modal')
        }
    },1000);
});
```

In the modal it shows content of what new functionality to the application is added. So my target is **to show the modal to the user every time I update the modal content**. How can I do this?

Comment: Change the cookie name when you update the modal content. (Though you should use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), so it wont get send to the server with every request. (Unless that is what you want ofcourse.))

Comment: set a timestamp/version number/unique hash in the cookie, when you update check for the new timestamp, if not matching show modal and reset users cookie with the new timestamp you are checking for.

Comment: @Ivar Already thought about that but it would be better if it checked somehow if the content is the same as before and if not it should show again

Comment: You mean without a page reload? Is the content of the modal loaded on page load or with an Ajax request?

Comment: @Ivar on page load. I mean when the content in the modal has been modified then de modal should load once. It will only show once every time when the content has been modified.

Comment: Then I don't really see the problem with changing the cookie name every time.

Comment: @Ivar check my answer, IMO that solution is easier because you won't have to change the cookie name manually :)

Comment: @EgonMeijers That's a good solution. You should hash it though, because cookies have a limit on their size. Also will the content of the cookie be send to your server with every request. I still recommend to use localStorage instead of cookies. (They work almost the same.) (BTW, I never said you had to change it manually. ;))

Comment: @Ivar Change it to `localStorage.setItem` and `localStorage.getItem`. I looked it up and it's better to use indeed. What do you mean with hash it?

Comment: @EgonMeijers With [hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) you can shrink the amound of data to a fixed size. When you change the data the hash will change as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentRelease = document.getElementById("version").innerHTML;
    var currCookie = Cookies.get('modalShown');
    setTimeout(function () {
        if(!currCookie || currCookie != currentRelease) {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
            Cookies.set('modalShown', currentRelease);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

The id `version` is part of `modal-content` so as soon as I change something within the content the user will see the modal again on first visit since the change in the content.

Answer (score 1):

You could use versionning in your cookies values :

```
var currentRelease = "1.0.1",
currCookie = Cookies.get('modalShown')

setTimeout(function(){
    if(!currCookie || currCookie != currentRelease) {
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
        Cookies.set('modalShown', currentrelease);
    } else {
        alert('You already saw the modal')
    }
},1000);
```

Note that this method forces you to update the value of "currentRelease"
you could also crypt the text content of the modal into md5 and use that value in your cookie, so whenever the modal value change, the md5 changes